# Web3js: How to show pending transactions on custom blockchain

Tags: express, blockchain, web3js

I have been working on custom local blockchain testnet and want to show pending transactions on custom block explorer.
So whenever GET request from frontend arrives, the api-server(Express) should response with pending transactions.
I first tried with `web3.eth`'s `getPendingTransactions` method but it always returned with an empty array.

Next, I tried with `web3.eth.subscribe`'s `'pendingTransactions'` option like the [docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-subscribe.html).

Below is the code what I tried.

**transactionController.js**

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3("ws://192.168.112.82:7001");
var pndTxns = [];

exports.pendingTransactions = (req, res) => {
web3.eth
      .subscribe("pendingTransactions", function (error, result) {
        if (!error) console.log(result);
        console.log(pndTxns);
      })
      .on("data", function (transaction) {
        pndTxns.push(transaction);
}

res.status(200).json({
  success: true,
  txns: pndTxns,
});
```

(Here, transactionController.js a controller for pending transactions router.)
But `pndTxns` in response always returns with empty arrary even though `pndTxns` in `web3.eth.subscribe` exist.

I think this is because web3.eth.subscribe actually build a web socket connection with the RPC node so that pndTxns can not go out of this method.

Finally, I tried with `etherjs` module like [this blog](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/defi/how-to-stream-pending-transactions-with-ethers-js) and following is the code.

```
var ethers = require("ethers");
var url = "ws://192.168.112.82:7001";

var init = function () {
  var customWsProvider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(url);
  
  customWsProvider.on("pending", (tx) => {
    customWsProvider.getTransaction(tx).then(function (transaction) {
      console.log(transaction);
    });
  });

  customWsProvider._websocket.on("error", async () => {
    console.log(`Unable to connect to ${ep.subdomain} retrying in 3s...`);
    setTimeout(init, 3000);
  });
  customWsProvider._websocket.on("close", async (code) => {
    console.log(
      `Connection lost with code ${code}! Attempting reconnect in 3s...`
    );
    customWsProvider._websocket.terminate();
    setTimeout(init, 3000);
  });
};

init();

res.status(200).json({
  success: true,
  txns: pndTxns,
});
```

Also I could see pending transactions inside `init()` function but could not send those transactions with a reponse.

Here is sample output of transaction inside `init` function.

```
[
  {
    hash: '0x4c34186e0e6fee5c83406660cf8ef830c36548bb3b8cc14a0fb1eb29fe438331',
    type: 0,
    accessList: null,
    blockHash: '0x000000c9000004c2e8c3585c051b49972b1de6a64c40ce7310a2a994b00483e4',
    blockNumber: 40964,
    transactionIndex: 0,
    confirmations: 1,
    from: '0x8734CB972d36a740Cc983d5515e160C373A4a016',
    gasPrice: BigNumber { _hex: '0x3b9aca00', _isBigNumber: true },
    gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x5208', _isBigNumber: true },
    to: '0x9651819cfa16c8F3Ba927d5350Ca25417591166B',
    value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x01236efcbcbb340000', _isBigNumber: true },
    nonce: 224,
    data: '0x',
    r: '0xed3d1d5b94a413ce45a06de77851865281cc41c8cdbbcbc4b96356b4d9e49e5c',
    s: '0x2d05d609590c1d5ff7e3ff69111cc6d3caf6f517c2e0229a10de8e938ccee1ba',
    v: 535,
    creates: null,
    chainId: 250,
    wait: [Function (anonymous)]
  }
]
```

I don't care whatever way you use but can you tell me how can I response pending transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `web3.eth`'s `getPendingTransactions` method returns an empty array because it's returning only transactions originating from an account on your node. Here's [the source code](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/ead814616c094331915b03edd82d4200a7880178/internal/ethapi/api.go#L1700) (assuming you are on Geth).

You can use `eth.subscribe` to get all the pending transactions:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const url = 'wss://ENDPOINT';
const web3 = new Web3(url);

var options = {
    address: null,
    topics: [
        null
    ]
};

var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', options, function(error, result){
    if (!error) console.log('got result');
    else console.log(error);
}).on("data", function(log){
    console.log('got data', log);
}).on("changed", function(log){
    console.log('changed');
});
```

[This might be useful too](https://support.chainstack.com/hc/en-us/articles/900003426246-Subscribing-to-global-new-pending-transactions-with-web3-js).